# How to make a geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have just started to learn data analysis, I am working on the cyclistic case study in the google coursera data analytics program. I am trying to make a geom_col but I am not able to.

First, I created a new column called "route" by merging start station name and end station name
Now there are two types of users "casual" and "members". I want to make geom_col of the top 10 routes which are common to both with casual and members trips shown side by side for easier comparison.

So I want a geom_col with route on the y axis, frequency of trips by members and casual users in the axis, with members and casual side by side for ease of comparison.

This is a sample of the original data set with only the relevant columns:

```
ride_id route member_casual
1       A        member   
2       A        casual  
3       B        member
4       C        casual
5       D        casual
There are 500 approx routes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `count()` function to count the frequency for each `route`  and `member_casual` combination. Adding the `name=` parameter lets you name the new column with the counts. `slice_max()` can then order the rows by the new frequency column that we called `freq`, then select the top n (10) rows. The default behavior for `slice_max()` is to keep ties, so you may get more than 10 results if the 10th `freq` value has a tie. You can add the parameter `with_ties = FALSE` to only return the top 10 rows, ignoring any ties that the `freq` value in the 10th row may have. Then you plot the `route` and `freq` and tell `ggplot` to fill the bar colors using the `member_casual` values. Add the `position="dodge"` parameter to `geom_col` (the default is "stack") so the `member_casual` bars show side by side for easier comparison. Then the `coord_flip` flips the graph to be a horizontal column plot.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataframe |>  
  count(route, member_casual, name="freq") |> 
  slice_max(order_by = freq, n = 10) |> 
  ggplot(aes(route, freq, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

Also, if you're looking for the top 10 routes for each type of member (ie. top 10 routes for casual and top 10 routes for member, you can add a `group_by(member_casual)` before `slice_max()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataframe |>  
  count(route, member_casual, name="freq") |> 
  group_by(member_casual) |>
  slice_max(order_by = freq, n = 10) |> 
  ggplot(aes(route, freq, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  coord_flip()
```

Comment: I am getting the following error ```Error in count(route, member_casual, name = "freq") : 
  unused argument (name = "freq")```

Comment: You might have another library loaded with a function of the same name. Try changing it to `dplyr::count()` to specify that the count() function you want to use is in the dplyr library.

Comment: It worked thanks ! Your help is much appreciated, also please correct groupby to group_by.

Comment: It worked but not exactly, it is showing top 10 of everything. For example there is a route in top 10 that is only members but not casual, or there is a route with casual but not members. I want top 10 that are common to both members and casual users. Any idea how to go about it.

Comment: This is the plot that has been generated, I want all columns to look like Ellis Ave & 60th Street to Ellis Ave and 55th Street. https://imgur.com/a/3vgj7s7

Comment: How do you want the ordering to work? Do you want the top 10 to be the top 10 combined (member frequency + casual frequency), but only routes that have both users?

Comment: No I do not want ordering like that I want top 10 routes that are common to both users but the columns should show members and casual separately in different colors, now after checking the columns generated the first columns " Wells St & Elm St to Wells St & Huron St " has both casual and members , but due to some reason it is showing only casual in the graph.

Comment: The code above is taking the top 10 of everything, so if Wells St & Elm St to Wells St & Huron St has a frequency of members that isn't high enough to put it in the top 10, then it won't show in the graph. You could add a `group_by(route) |>
  filter(any(member_casual == "member"),
          any(member_casual == "casual")) |> 
  ungroup() |>` before `slice()` to filter for only the routes in common and then slice will take the top combinations after that. But you can still end up with some that won't show up in the graph since you're just looking at the top 10

Comment: But one way to ensure that you are always showing both is to use the route's member/casual combined frequency to order the top 10, then split then out to separate bars when you plot the graph, but it sounds like that's not what you're looking for?

Comment: Wells St & Elm St to Wells St & Huron St does have a frequency of members that is high enough to show in the graph, the casual user trips are 931 and the member trips are 1240. It should show the members. I want the graph to show both members and casual per route separated by color  as done in Ellis Ave & 60th Street to Ellis Ave and 55th Street.

Comment: It looks like from the plot that you're taking the top ten for each user type. So it is getting the 10 highest frequencies out of all the stations for casual users and the 10 highest frequencies out of all the stations for member users. And the lowest frequency for members on the plot is around 1800 (the university ave bar), so I wouldn't expect a member frequency of 1240 to show in that plot. So since 10 or more stations have higher frequency counts for members, it won't show on the graph.

Comment: Would this work?: `data frame |> dplyr::count(route, member_casual, name="freq") |>
  group_by(route) |>   
  filter(
    any(member_casual == "member"), 
    any(member_casual == "casual")
    )|>    
  summarize(
    total_freq = sum(freq), 
    member_casual, 
    user_freq = freq, 
    .groups="drop"
    ) |> 
  group_by(member_casual) |> 
  slice_max(order_by = total_freq, n = 10) |> 
  ggplot(aes(route, user_freq, fill=member_casual)) +
  geom_col(position="dodge") +
  coord_flip() `